# обновление приложения у старых пользователей

Tags: app

Всем привет такой вопрос к разработчикам мобильного приложения, кто может подсказать если приложение планомерно выпускалось в течений года , и сейчас я придумал заглушку , а именно при заходе в приложение если есть апдейт на площадках не давать доступ( требовать обновиться). но данная заглушка начнет работать сейчас, а как быть с пользователями с старой версией приложения. можно ли как то придумать сценарий что бы их тоже заставить обновиться. просто сейчас функционал далеко ушел вперед а пользователи со старой версией сталкиваются с неправильной логикой

как либо через google play console? или данного сценария нет и только время поможет)

Comment: Так и писать на заглушке, что нужно обновиться, иначе приложение не будет работать или будут доступны не все функции или как там у вас. (Это намного лучше, чем просто молча отключать функции в старых версиях и ничего не сообщать пользователю. Знаю пару таких приложений)

Comment: понял спасибо за совет. просто думал у гугла есть такой функционал где можно выставить  минимальную версию апк , и если у пользователя не тот апк который выставлен то доступ к приложению не давать